# Gremlin: how to traverse backwards across the same edge

Tags: gremlin

I have a simple graph with two vertices, having ids 'a' and 'b'.

I have assigned an edge from 'a' to 'b' with label = 'foo'

gremlin> g.V()

==>v[b]

==>v[a]

gremlin> g.E()

==>e[04b4b9fd-2f20-751d-5673-5aa9d7ce0285][a-foo->b]

My question: how do I traverse backwards along the same edge? For example, if a query traverses to an outbound vertex, how can that query then traverse back across the same edge to the inbound vertex?

My query is shown below:

g.E('04b4b9fd-2f20-751d-5673-5aa9d7ce0285').outV().as('outV')...[want to get the inV for the same edge, here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to do this. Here's a few that will hopefully inspire you to your answer. You probably shouldn't count on the order in which the vertices are returned in the following case, but you could do `bothV()`:

```
gremlin> g.E(11).bothV()
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
```

To force order you could do a `union()`:

```
gremlin> g.E(11).union(inV(),outV())
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
```

You could always `project()` your results:

```
gremlin> g.E(11).project('in','out').by(inV()).by(outV())
==>[in:v[3],out:v[4]]
```

If you need to do something with the `outV()` first and then come back to the edge after that to then traverse on `inV()` you could label the `E()` step with `as()`:

```
gremlin> g.E(11).as('e').outV().hasLabel('person').select('e').inV()
==>v[3]
```

Hopefully, those examples help.